# Mono Won't Open

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

I have the free version of Unity. I installed Mono and the gtk#. I also have the newest .Net version. But it give me this whenever I try to open Mono, whether it be from unity or from my files.

**Screenshot of error message.**

[image]

Comment: Isn't using GTK# at odds with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

First, try uninstalling mono-develop and re installing it, saving any previously created programs before hand. It has been noted that the bug lies within the GTK# for .Net 2.12.26, so your second option is to uninstall that. You can find it in the Programs and Features section of control panel (if you're using windows). There is a link to the installer here: http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win

I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Well no, the reason is because OP is not using the bundled version of Mono with Unity as [Programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37313031/585968) mentions above

Answer (score 0):

> I installed Mono and the gtk#

That's the problem there. Unity does **not** use the official Mono program. Unity uses in-house customized version of Mono that does not even come gtk. You **must** download/install Mono from Unity software during installation not from the Mono website.

If you really want to use gtk, you have to install the official version of Mono in another directory and the Mono from Unity in another directory.